# \includepdf as an appendix

Tags: appendices, pdfpages

I have appendices using `\includepdf`.

How can I make these a labeled appendix that appears in the heading? i.e. `process.pdf` = Appendix A

```
%!TEX root = ../main.tex
\begin{appendices}
\section{Project Proposal}
\includepdf[pages={1,2,3,4,5,6},scale=0.8]{Partridge.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1,2},scale=0.8]{chapters/proposal.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{chapters/shedule.pdf}
\includepdf[landscape=true]{process.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{chapters/consent_form_final.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1,2},scale=0.8]{Balkan_Rail_Requirements_Specification.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1,2},scale=0.8]{control_requirements.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{chapters/affinity.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{chapters/cd_content.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I provide a MWE to solve your problem

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Document

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}

\appendix

\includepdf[pages=1, pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}, addtotoc={1, section, 2, The section title, sec:sectionref}]{1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: Contens]
[image: Pdf included with title in appendix format]

I prefer add `fancyhdr` package to have a better inclusion of appendix in the whole document. It permits to have page numerotation and so on.

Now, you have just to adapt your includepdf with this structure.

Comment: addtotoc={1, section, 2, The section title, sec:sectionref}

What do the 1 & 2 here do?


I found this addtotoc={⟨page number ⟩,⟨section ⟩,⟨level ⟩,⟨heading ⟩,⟨label ⟩}
⟨page number ⟩: Page number of the inserted page.
6
⟨section⟩: LATEX sectioning name – e.g., section, subsection, . . .
⟨level⟩: Number, denoting depth of section – e.g., 1 for section level, 2 for
subsection level, . . .
⟨heading⟩: Title inserted in the table of contents.
⟨label⟩: Name of the label. This label can be referred to with \ref and
\pageref.

Comment: But still not quite sure what ⟨page number ⟩, ⟨level⟩ did. I made the inserted pages as Chapter not section.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use you might prefer to simply use `minipage`.
E.g.

```
\newpage
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
    \vspace{-2in}
    \section*{Appendix A}
    \includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8]{my.pdf}  % first page w/ header
\end{minipage}
\includepdf[pages=2-]{my.pdf}    % more pages w/o header
```