# \includepdf takes heading from chapter

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
\bibliography{Referenties}
\newpage
\includepdf[fitpaper=true, pages={-}, angle=0, pagecommand={}]{laatstepagina.pdf}
\markboth{}{}
\end{document}
```

I have included a page after my `bibtex`, as I will print my report with a full color page as the last page. Somehow the heading of my `bibliography` is ending up on my included `.pdf`.

Comment: Remove `pagecommand={}` from the options of `\includepdf` to get an empty page style on the included pdf pages. You can also try `pagecommand={\pagstyle{plain}}` or `pagecommand{\markboth{}{}}`.

Comment: Does this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309070/97981 helps you?

Comment: @esdd Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `pagecommand={}` from the option list of `\includepdf`. Then the default `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{empty}` will be used.

If the page style should be the same as on the other pages then use `\markboth` between `\clearpage` and `\includepdf`:

```
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true, pages={-}, angle=0, pagecommand={}]{laatstepagina.pdf}
```

Or use a different page style like `plain`: `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: danke schön :-)